# Unable to Push git tags from remote?

Tags: git, github, git-remote, git-tag

I'm trying to create some tags on a local clone and push it to master, and delete a tag from remote and push it to my local clone, to be clear, the remote is github, but were talking about tags, not releases.

I create a tag the tag `v0.1-beta` on remote.
I create a tag `v1.0-full-release` on local.

I'm noticing that even after a git fetch, git pull, and git push on my local end that nether side see's each others tags.

I looked it up and found that you could use `git fetch --tags` to fetch tags from remote, so now my local client is up to date. But I can't find a way to push my local `v1.0-full-release` tag to remote. `Git push` isn't doing it, and I can't find anything in the documentation.

SideNote: I've done most of my testing in the terminal, but I also notice in both Github for desktop, Kitkracken, and Gmaster that when I created the tag locally, and the other on the remote, fetching or pushing from those clients would't sync the tags ether.

If someone could also explain why it was decided that the standard `git fetch`, `git pull`, and `git push` shouldn't include tags by default, that would also be great.

Comment: This link seems to be saying that you need to use 'git push [remote] --tags'

https://www.drupixels.com/blog/git-tags-guide-create-delete-push-tags-remote-and-much-more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While `git fetch` *does* include `--tags` by default, it doesn't include `--tags` by default.

[(insert record-scratch sound effect here)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z_rBo-M9MgY)  Wait, what?

OK, the trick is: `git fetch` will bring over tags *when it brings over the commit that has the tag attached to it.*  There are some variations on the overall theme (or at least, bugs in specific corner cases) in different versions of Git, but in general, if you don't have the tagged commit yet, and you run `git fetch` without either `--tags` or `--no-tags`, you'll get *both* the commit *and* the tag.  But if you already have the commit, and you run `git fetch` without `--tags`, you *don't* get the tag.

By contrast, `git push` without `--tags` *never* pushes tags, at least if you don't configure various settings.  It often makes sense to just run:

`git push origin tag-name`

to explicitly push one particular tag anyway.

Comment: Thank you such much for the explanation! As a side question may I ask why it was decided that git fetch pulls down the tags if the local repo doesn't have the commit at all, while it was decided that git push won't send the tags under any circumstances unless the --tags flag was added?

Comment: You'd have to ask the Git authors. It does make sense that you can't set a tag for which you don't have a commit (no ref can exist unless the object it refers to also exists). So if you've limited your initial `git fetch` in some way, you've thereby limited which tags you can have as well. But the rest is a design decision and you'd have to ask the designers.